# How to "export" all overloads of one function in c++?

Tags: c++, overriding, overloading, accessor

I have a class `FooBar` that contains a member of type `Foo`. This type can be inherited from so that `FooBar` has variable behaviour. `Foo` contains multiple overloads for the accessor method `bar`.

```
class FooBar;

class Foo{
    friend class FooBar;

    virtual void bar(int barIn){ bar_ = barIn; }
    virtual void bar(int barIn, float barScale){ bar(int(barIn * barScale)); }
    virtual void bar(const Foo& barSource){ bar(barSource.bar_); }
    int bar(){ return bar_; }

    int bar_;
};

class FooBar{
public:
    void bar(int barIn){ foo_.bar(barIn); }
    void bar(int barIn, float barScale){ foo_.bar(barIn, barScale); }
    void bar(const Foo& barSource){ foo_.bar(barSource); }
    int bar(){ return foo_.bar(); }
private:
    Foo& foo_;
};
```

Looks ok so far, but I feel like all the definitions for the `FooBar.bar` accessor are kind of unnecessary. I know that the compiler inlines them, so there should be no overhead, but the methods all got the same name and are all overloads of each other.

*Is there a way in C++ to "export" (I haven't found a better word) the accessor so calls to `FooBar.bar` are just redirected to `FooBar.foo_.bar`?*

One idea I had was overriding the `operator ->` for `FooBar`, but the real case has multiple classes like `Foo`, so that would only work for one of them.

Comment: Read about slicing in C++. Your FooBar class probably doesn't do what you want. (I don't believe there are any generic ways to do the sort of "proxy"ing you want.)

Comment: The member `Foo foo_` should be reference/pointer. Otherwise all of the `FooBar::bar` methods will simply call corresponding `Foo::bar` methods, they will not behave polymorphic for the derived classes of `Foo`. If you try to send the `foo_` to `FooBar` from outside, then sending a derived class object of 'Foo' will be sliced and you will face unexpected behavior and hard to find errors. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing)

Comment: @RakibulHasan oh I didn't think about that. In the real case, it is in a fact a `unique_ptr`. Answer gets edited right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write a real generic forwarder:

```
class FooBar
{
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    auto bar(Args&&... args) -> decltype(foo_.bar(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
    {
        return foo_.bar(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

private:
    Foo& foo_;
};
```

(this requires C++11, with C++14 you could even leave out the `->decltype...` part)

Comment: That looks exactly like what I was searching for. Does a forwarder induce any overhead?

Comment: @iFreilicht When it's inlined, there is no overhead. And I think it's quite likely that it will be inlined.